# Scala sort one list according to the values in another one

Tags: list, scala

I have two IndexedSeq

```
works[Work]
order[Int]
```

Each object Work has an id field with integer value: Work.id
In order lists there are ids, which are in the order we need to sort out the work. Like, in position 0 there is a first id, so we need to find the work in the works array with id that corresponds this one, and put it in the 0 place and so on. 
Is there any way to do this with scala without going through two loops?Like, some elegant way?
Some pseudo data, for example:

```
order = 33, 22, 11, 55

works = (33, "some text"), (55, "eeeee"), (22, "fdsfs"), (11, "fdsffds")
```

After the sorting:

```
order = 33, 22, 11, 55

works = (33, "some text"),(22, "fdsfs"),  (11, "fdsffds"), (55, "eeeee"),
```

Comment: Zip them together, sort, then unzip again?

Comment: sounds strange0_o how this is going to work, exactly?

Comment: Surely there is a way. Post sample data for the `IndexedSeq` `works` and `orders` and what you want the output to look like.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use dictionary for that, the complexity would be linear which is better in comparision with quadratic for two nested cycles:

```
scala> val order = List(33, 22, 11, 55)
order: List[Int] = List(33, 22, 11, 55)

scala> val works = List((33, "some text"), (55, "eeeee"), (22, "fdsfs"), (11, "fdsffds"))
works: List[(Int, String)] = List((33,some text), (55,eeeee), (22,fdsfs), (11,fdsffds))

scala> val worksMap = works.toMap
worksMap: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,String] = Map(33 -> some text, 55 -> eeeee, 22 -> fdsfs, 11 -> fdsffds)

scala> val newWorks = order zip order.map(worksMap)
newWorks: List[(Int, String)] = List((33,some text), (22,fdsfs), (11,fdsffds), (55,eeeee))
```

if your entities are more than tuples:

```
scala> val worksMap = (works map (_._1) zip works).toMap //any other key extraction, like `_.myKey` may be applied instead of `_._1`
worksMap: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,(Int, String)] = Map(33 -> (33,some text), 55 -> (55,eeeee), 22 -> (22,fdsfs), 11 -> (11,fdsffds))

scala> order.map(worksMap)
res13: List[(Int, String)] = List((33,some text), (22,fdsfs), (11,fdsffds), (55,eeeee))
```

if you don't want to spent memory on a Map - just use `find` instead of  `Map.apply` (but it would be O(N*N), so it's slower):

```
scala> val newWorks = order.map(x => works.find(_._1 == x).get)
newWorks: List[(Int, String)] = List((33,some text), (22,fdsfs), (11,fdsffds), (55,eeeee))
```

If you don't want to have an exception in case if `order` doesn't contain your key, you could use `flatMap`:

```
scala> val newWorks = order.flatMap(x => works.find(_._1 == x))
newWorks: List[(Int, String)] = List((33,some text), (22,fdsfs), (11,fdsffds), (55,eeeee))

scala> order.flatMap(worksMap.get)
res15: List[(Int, String)] = List((33,some text), (22,fdsfs), (11,fdsffds), (55,eeeee))
```

Comment: i really like how the second one looks, let me test that:)

Answer (score 9):

You might be interested in the `sortWith` method:

```
works.sortWith((a, b) => order.indexOf(a._1) < order.indexOf(b._1))
```

Comment: just to mention that complexity here is about `O(N * N * logN) > O(N*N)` as `indexOf` is linear

Comment: Sure -- inefficient in this case, but I just wanted to bring up the `sortWith` method, and in many small cases the complexity isn't as important as the readability!

Comment: As I said, "just to mention", no critics :)

Answer (score 5):

You can convert the `Seq[Work]` to a `Map[WorkId, Work]` and `collect` the values from the map in the same order as the `Seq[WorkId]`.

For example:

```
case class Work(id: Int, text: String)
// defined class Work

val order = Seq(33, 22, 11, 55)
// order: Seq[Int] = List(33, 22, 11, 55)

val works = Seq(Work(33, "some text"), Work(55, "eeeee"), Work(22, "fdsfs"), Work(11, "fdsffds"))
// works: Seq[Work] = List(Work(33, "some text"), Work(55, "eeeee"), Work(22, "fdsfs"), Work(11, "fdsffds"))

val workMap = works.map(work => work.id -> work).toMap
// workMap: Map[Int, Work] = Map(33 -> Work(33, "some text"), 55 -> Work(55, "eeeee"), 22 -> Work(22, "fdsfs"), 11 -> Work(11, "fdsffds"))

order.collect(workMap)
// res14: Seq[Work] = List(Work(33, "some text"), Work(22, "fdsfs"), Work(11, "fdsffds"), Work(55, "eeeee"))
```

This is similar to the other answers but uses `collect`, which works because `Map[A, B]` is also a `PartialFunction[A, B]`.

---

However, the above solution assumes work IDs are unique.

In the case where work ID isn't unique, you can use `groupBy` and `flatMap`:

```
val works = Seq(Work(33, "a"), Work(34, "b"), Work(33, "c"), Work(35, "d"))
// works: Seq[Work] = List(Work(33, "a"), Work(34, "b"), Work(33, "c"), Work(35, "d"))

val worksMap = works.groupBy(_.id)
//worksMap: Map[Int, Seq[Work]] = Map(35 -> List(Work(35, "d")), 34 -> List(Work(34, "b")), 33 -> List(Work(33, "a"), Work(33, "c")))

val order = Seq(35, 34, 33)
//order: Seq[Int] = List(35, 34, 33)

order.flatMap(id => worksMap.getOrElse(id, Seq.empty))
// res23: Seq[Work] = List(Work(35, "d"), Work(34, "b"), Work(33, "a"), Work(33, "c"))
```

Comment: This should actually be flagged as the correct answer, It's super simple and works very well.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you have your data in `List`, here is what you can do:

```
scala> val order = List(33, 22, 11, 55)
order: List[Int] = List(33, 22, 11, 55)

scala> val works = List((33, "some text"), (55, "eeeee"), (22, "fdsfs"), (11, "fdsffds"))
works: List[(Int, String)] = List((33,some text), (55,eeeee), (22,fdsfs), (11,fdsffds))

scala> val sortedWorks = order.flatMap( id => works.find(x => x._1 == id ))
sortedWorks: List[(Int, String)] = List((33,some text), (22,fdsfs), (11,fdsffds), (55,eeeee))
```

Now you can optmize the part that looks up work by id, using a Map, which will make it like so:

```
scala> val worksMap = works.toMap
worksMap: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,String] = Map(33 -> some text, 55 -> eeeee, 22 -> fdsfs, 11 -> fdsffds)

scala> val sortedWorks = order.flatMap( id => worksMap.get(id))
sortedWorks: List[String] = List(some text, fdsfs, fdsffds, eeeee)
```

Peformance will depend on the lookup. In this case it is amortized O(N), because of HashMap.